# gfortran error: cannot execute 'f951': execvp: No such file or directory when downloading Bioconductor package

Tags: r, installation, bioconductor

When I download a package (DESeq2) from Bioconductor, I got the following error:

*gfortran: fatal error: cannot execute 'f951': execvp: No such file or directory compilation terminated.*

However, when I check my opt/R/arm64/bin folder, gfortran and f951 are inside. I'm wondering why the f951 file cannot be executed and how to fix this problem?

[image]